# How to generate files from a list of file names contained inside a .txt file?

Tags: php, batch-file, code-generation, cmd, text-files

I have a .txt file that includes a list of about 500 file names. I need to generate the actual files based on the list. I could use either CMD locally, or PHP. Which ever is best. Each file name is on a separate line within the .txt and there is no other punctuation or syntax. Let's say, for example, the .txt file is named colors.txt: and EACH LINE inside the text file contains a unique file name, like this:

```
red.php
blue.php
green.php
orange.php
yellow.php
magenta.php
light-yellow.php
purple.php
```

How would I go about actually turning these names in the list into files? And, better yet, is there a way to include content into the files as they are generated? For example, if I wanted to insert `<?echo "hello world";?>` automatically within each and every new .php file as it was being created, how could I? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: This is a batch-script for windows.

To create these files from your colors.txt list and add the echo line to each file, use the following `FOR /F` loop:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (colors.txt) DO (
  (ECHO ^<?echo "hello world";?^>)>"%%A"
)
```

Notice in the `ECHO` command you must escape the `<` and `>` characters with `^` to make them into a literal string or else the batch script will think they are redirection commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here. My gut tells me there may be a better way to solve the bigger picture problem you are dealing with. Nonetheless, you could try something like the following:

```
foreach (file('colors.txt') as $filename) {
    file_put_contents($filename, '<?php echo "hello world";');
}
```

You would probably also want to do some sanity checking on the filenames to make sure they are safe to use.

Comment: Thank you. I put that code by itself in an index.php file (same dir as the .txt file). Opened index.php in browswer, it worked great but only generated one file, the last file in the text list. There are over fifty file names in the text list. Any ideas?